# NumberFormat do intl-Dart faz parse errado de um número com ponto em pt_BR?

Tags: dart

Estou usando o package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) do Dart pra fazer parse de números com parte decimal. Ao setar o locale pra 'pt_BR', eu esperaria que um número no formato inglês (1.5 ao invés de 1,5) lançasse um FormatException. Mas ele faz o parse ignorando o ponto:

```
print(NumberFormat.decimalPattern('pt_BR').parse('1.5'))
15.0
```

To deixando passar alguma coisa besta, ou é isso mesmo? Isso seria um bug no package intl (me parece improvável)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, pode até parecer estranho mas é dessa forma que a lib foi desenvolvida. Para o locale `pt_BR` o caractere `.` (ponto) é considerado um caractere de separação de grupo (GROUP_SEP).

[Fonte](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/number_symbols_data.dart#L1600): arquivo `number_symbols_data.dart`:

```dart
"pt_BR": new NumberSymbols(
      NAME: "pt_BR",
      DECIMAL_SEP: ',',
      GROUP_SEP: '.',
      PERCENT: '%',
      ZERO_DIGIT: '0',
      PLUS_SIGN: '+',
      MINUS_SIGN: '-',
      EXP_SYMBOL: 'E',
      PERMILL: '\u2030',
      INFINITY: '\u221E',
      NAN: 'NaN',
      DECIMAL_PATTERN: '#,##0.###',
      SCIENTIFIC_PATTERN: '#E0',
      PERCENT_PATTERN: '#,##0%',
      CURRENCY_PATTERN: '\u00A4\u00A0#,##0.00',
      DEF_CURRENCY_CODE: 'BRL')
```

E por ser reconhecido como um caractere de separação, ele é simplesmente ignorado durante o parse do número. Afinal em pt_BR um número **1.234.567,00** é a mesma coisa que **1234567,00**. Por isso um **1.5** acaba virando um **15**.

[Fonte](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/fee2c2d16999d2e211354ecd2179f012ae4f93bd/lib/src/intl/number_parser.dart#L183): trecho da função `processNonDigit()` do arquivo `number_parser.dart`:

```dart
  void processNonDigit() {
    // It might just be a prefix that we haven't skipped. We don't want to
    // skip them initially because they might also be semantically meaningful,
    // e.g. leading %. So we allow them through the loop, but only once.
    var foundAnInterpretation = false;
    if (input.index == 0 && !prefixesSkipped) {
      prefixesSkipped = true;
      checkPrefixes(skip: true);
      foundAnInterpretation = true;
    }

    for (var key in replacements.keys) {
      if (input.startsWith(key)) {
        _normalized.write(replacements[key]!()); // aqui
        input.read(key.length);
        return;
      }
    }
    // We haven't found either of these things, this seems invalid.
    if (!foundAnInterpretation) {
      done = true;
    }
  }
```

Nesta função o trecho é onde ocorre a chamada dos valores do map `replacements[key]!()`. Que se investigar mais a fundo verá que para este `GROUP_SEP` é chamado uma outra função `handleSpace()` para tratar de valores que são indiferentes para o formato do número no locale.

Comment: Interessante, obrigado pela resposta detalhada. Eu imaginaria que a lib conferiria que tem 3 dígitos depois do GROUP_SEP (talvez essa regra seja mais complexa pra outras línguas?). Vou adicionar uma validação própria pro caso 'ponto não seguido por 3 dígitos' antes de mandar pra lib então.